# Binding Textblock in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, controls

Im learning WPF and c# and i trying to make textblock binding in usercontrol.

I have class Seller.cs

```
  public class SellerInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public float workTime { get; set; }
        public float loginTime { get; set; }
        public int soldTickets { get; set; }
        public int ticketReservation { get; set; }
        public float totalAmountP { get; set; }
    }
```

And i want to get that data from db by

```
 public void accountInfo()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-8T7J7IH;Initial Catalog=Db1234;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        string s1 = @"SELECT Name +' ' + Surname FROM Seller WHERE LoginUser = '12345'";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(s1, con);
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        do
        {
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                {
                    SellerInfo item = new SellerInfo();
                    item.Name = rd.GetString(0);

                };
            }
        }
        while (rd.NextResult());
        rd.Close();

    }
```

At the example above only name, now i have question how to bind what i got to textblock and show it in usercontrol?

I created something like:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="sellerName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="166"/>
```

And read about it, in UserControl i should use `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` later i tried to set `DataContext=this;` but it still without result. I read a lot articles about it but i cant figure it out how to get it on this example.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up a bit on MVVM.
Samples which set datacontext to self are all very well in that they "work" but they're trivial.  Almost nobody is going to do that commercially.

In MVVM you have a viewmodel - a class implementing inotifypropertychanged. This acts as a sort of adapter between the view and the model. The model being your data and that code with the datareader.
Your viewmodel would call that code and present data in an observablecollection to the view.
Each of those "rows" of data are often themselves viewmodels.

There are numerous ways to instantiate a viewmodel and set it as the datacontext of a view.  One of the simplest being to do so in XAML.
You can see some very basic introductory code here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31915.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-1.aspx
and
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32164.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-2.aspx

Almost all commercial teams use an ORM like entity framework or dapper which returns objects filled with data rather than having to work column by column.

Unfortunately, the step from no-mvvm-experience to working commercial level database orientated app is huge so explaining all that in a forum post isn't really so practical.

Answer (score 1):

Have you implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: No im not should I to get results? I just want to open simple window with dB infomation with binding use

Comment: I just check with your scenario, What I have observed that when you type something in binded textbox it will updates the binded property in code behind, but if you change the Property value from code behind it won't reflect on the UI i.e Text inside Textbox.

Comment: So, that is why better make use of INotifyPropertyChanged interface in order to reflect the changes on both side i.e. on UI and code, and it also saves runtime Memory and CPU.